# Why can curved spacetime be locally a Minkowskian spacetime?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, curvature

The gravity field is determined by the metric $\eta_{\mu \nu}$ we impose on a flat (Minkowskian) spacetime, for which the metric has diagonal elements only: $(1,-1,-1,-1)$. Solving the Einstein equation gives you the space- and time components of the metric if a stress-energy tensor $T_{\mu \nu}$ is present. Time variations in the metric represent gravitational waves.
So we can say that the gravity field is a metric field defined on a flat (Minkowskian) spacetime and from this we can calculate what the real (non-Minkowskian) spacetime looks like (if a stress-energy tensor is present). How can we say that locally this curved spacetime is Minkowskian if a Minkowskian metric is only there in Minkowskian spacetime? Isn't it Minkowskian everywhere if it's locally so?

Of course, by looking close enough, you can say the curved spacetime looks flat (like a function can be approximated by a linear function for small values of its argument). If curved spacetime looks flat locally, then why will mass move in curved paths?

Comment: Your final question is essentially answered [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/9876)

Comment: The local tangent space at a point is flat, but you can't non-trivially connect these different tangent spaces together. Hence the need for parallel transport and the connection, which is related to the definition of curvature itself.

Comment: When you use calculus a curve is approximated by small straight lines.You have to do this for curved space.Look at the second minute of this video  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UfThVvBWZxM